# How can I get specific values contained within a repeating 'xsl:when' element?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT from which I need to pull node values from into a list..

```
<ServiceDetails>
  <xsl:for-each select="$TagList">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(@ItemName, 'Test1')">
        <Qty>
          <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
        </Qty>
        <ReasonCode>
          <__name>Value1</__name>
        </ReasonCode>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:for-each select="$TagList">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(@ItemName, 'Test2')">
        <Qty>
          <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
        </Qty>
        <ReasonCode>
          <__name>Value2</__name>
        </ReasonCode>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ServiceDetails>
```

I need to pull values from `<__name>` and an attribute within the `<xsl:when>` element. (In this Example: Test1, Test2)

I want the output to look like this:

```
Test1  Value1
Test2  Value2
```

I've been able to output a single node using the code below, but the formatting ends up with excess spacing and indentation in the output text file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
     <xsl:template match="/ServiceDetails">
          <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="ReasonCode">
           <xsl:value-of select="__name/text()"/>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see anything in your stylesheet that attempts to output the first column (`Test1`, `Test2`).

Secondly, the reason that you have excess whitespace in the output is that the built-in template rules are copying all the (whitespace) text nodes from the input to the output. You can suppress this with

```
<xsl:template match="text()/>
```

Comment: Thank you! and that makes complete sense now regarding the excess spacing. I haven't included the second column, because I'm trying to figure out how to actual access the 'Test1' element. So trying to piece that syntax together.